# Running Angular2 Project without Server

Tags: apache, angular, tomcat

Please bear with me if my question is too silly.I have just started learning Angular2. When i created angular2 project is eclipse neon it and when i run it as Angular2 Web Application, it shows a web page with message "App Works".

I have one question here how it's showing the web page even when i have not configure any server like Apache-tomcat.I remember that when we create any jsp or servlet application, even to display the index.html we run the application in apache-tomcat, so how it's different in Angular2.

Thanks

Comment: You have nodejs installed ?

Comment: @BabarBilal I think yes. Does it get installed with Angular IDE plugin in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 is a front end framework. HTML, JavaScript and CSS can work in the web browser without web server.

When you run Angular 2 application, you must be using lite-server which is a light weight web server that runs on node.  I am sure you must have installed Node.js and npm and then ran your application using the example code provided by Angular 2.

Apache Tomcat is an application server + web server.  But like I said above, you do not need an application server or web server to render your HTML, JavaScript and CSS.  The browser can very well render these things without a web server if your paths are relative and correctly mapped.

Comment: Why do you need node if you can run it just from the browser as it is just html+js+css?

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 runs using nodejs and this is the beauty of nodejs that you can just install it and via GUI/terminal as well and it can run in any directory of your system and take control over it.

Comment: So is Nodejs a alternate option of webserver ?